# Nós realmente precisamos da tag mercadolivre?

Tags: debate, tags

Me deparei hoje com [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167039/18246) que usa a tag [mercadolivre](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mercadolivre).

Entrei nas perguntas desta tag e vi que o site tem **7 perguntas** com esta tag, sendo a maioria (não vi todas) sobre a API de integração do mesmo.

Tendo em vista que as perguntas tratam sobre integração, requisições HTTP, etc. É realmente necessário que exista essa tag?

Comment: Em tese sim tanto quanto de `facebook`, mas não sei se está sendo usada corretamente.

Comment: Eu acho que devia ser api-mercadolivre e api-facebook (open-graph de repente no caso do FB, assim como google-maps é uma API. e bem específica). Não acho que possa ser tag genérica.

Comment: @Bacco eu acho uma boa

Comment: @Bacco Acho muito melhor do que usar só `mercadolivre`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

É necessário ter a *tag* até para 2 perguntas. O número de uso não pode determinar se a *tag* é útil ou não.

Ser usada corretamente ou não, não deve ser um critério primário para escolher que não deve ser usada. Só em casos muito específicos o mau uso pode ser usado para evitá-la, mesmo assim teria que ser muito mau uso.

Ela serve para indicar que está falando da API do Mercado Livre, portanto é fundamental para quem quiser achar perguntas postadas sobre esse assunto. É o mesmo caso de [facebook](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook).

Eu consertei o que tinha de problema nelas. Por mim ela fica porque é útil.

Comment: De acordo. Serve a lógica inversa, também: se alguém entra [numa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54138/) com as tags `php`, `json` e `api` mas é incapaz de responder por não deter conhecimento específico sobre a API do ML, não foi uma falha de categorização da pergunta? Tags devem - dentro do possível - ser um sinal claro do que é necessário saber para poder responder à pergunta.

Comment: Bem observado @Gabe, acredito que a tag **[tag:mercadolivre]** poderia ser melhorada para deixar claro que as perguntas não devem ser sobre anúncios, e sim sobre a API. A descrição atual só diz o que é o mercado livre. Embora eu tenha editado inicialmente essa wiki, qualquer um pode aprimora-la se assim desejar.